# iText to generate PDF with Chinese characters, but not displayed

Tags: pdf, encoding, fonts, itext

I'm using iText to create a PDF with Chinese characters. The Font I specified is MS Mincho which I had loaded using the code,

```
FontFactory.registerDirectory("c:/windows/Fonts/");

new Phrase("Asian 汉字/漢字 characters", FontFactory.getFont("MS Mincho", 16, Font.NORMAL));
```

The code below retrieves appropriately the MS Mincho font (i.e. not null),

```
FontFactory.getFont("MS Mincho", 16, Font.NORMAL)
```

However, the generated PDF only displays the ASCII text "Asian  characters", i.e. the  chinese characters are not displayed on the PDF.

Any idea as to why the chinese characters are missing on the generated PDF?

Comment: You should make sure that you a) use the font with an appropriate [encoding](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=394) (`BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`) and b) [embed](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=71) it (`BaseFont.EMBEDDED`). Be inspired by the samples from [chaptrer 11](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

Comment: Thanks. The generated PDF now displays the Chinese characters properly. No need to call the FontFactory.registerDirectory(). Just use BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/Fonts/MSMINCHO.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED) and instantiate Font(BaseFont, size). FontFactory.getFont("MS Mincho") does not work with Chinese characters.

Comment: Actually `FontFactory` can likewise be used to create appropriately parameterized font objects. But true, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

As the issue has been resolved in comments, here the resolution:

You should make sure that you a) use the font with an appropriate [encoding](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=394) (BaseFont.IDENTITY_H) and b) [embed](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=71) it (BaseFont.EMBEDDED). Be inspired by the [samples from chapter 11](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/Fonts/MSMINCHO.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font f = Font(bf, size);
```

Now use this `Font f.`

Answer (score 0):

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

This works for me, you can have a try.

Comment: this does not work for me. Do I need any font dll?